# Hosting Provider for CiviCRM

Tags: database, permissions, installation, hosting-providers

I am trying to install my CiviCRM instance on my current drupal installation that is my website which is hosted by the webgo24.de. During installation  I get an error „DB Error“ and after some emails between my Hoster and me he came back with the info that the required permissions I need for the database for CiviCRM are Admin permissions and they can‘t give me those.

Do you have an idea on how to solve that in general? Is there a smaller version that does not require all the rights? How are you setting up CiviCRM? Own server, cloud server or root server with Hoster?

Thanks for your help?
Said

Comment: This isn't an answer - but if you search stack exchange - you will see many posts about hosting providers - Shared, VPS, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the list of required permissions here: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/#mysql-permissions

You might want to check out some of the options for hosting here https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors?country_1=All&services=Hosting&language=All&cms=All

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to set up Drupal on the server, then you probably already have the needed permissions since Drupal has it's own database which can also be used for CiviCRM. Did you set up Drupal yourself, or was it prepackaged?

Comment: This isn't true - Drupal doesn't need the `TRIGGER` permission, which CiviCRM does.  You may also need `REFERENCES` and `CREATE VIEW` depending on MySQL version and whether you're using CiviCase, neither of which are necessary for Drupal.

That said - these are NOT "admin" permissions.  This sounds like the case of a shared host company who doesn't have a system capable of giving out unusual permissions to non-admins.  Plenty of shared hosting providers can support this.

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech you are right. CiviCRM needs some more rights. I just reasked my provider which of the required rights according to https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/#mysql-permissions are from there perspective Admin-Permissions. Will push them again and check if they can do something. Thanks alot!

Comment: Thanks @JonG-MegaphoneTech, looks like I misread the question.